# how do I export campared results in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi iahe compared two table and got results of the same. but these results are in thousands of pages. so how do I export the same to text.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE username NOT 
IN (

SELECT username
FROM table2
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

To export your query result from PHPMyAdmin

There is an block named "Query results operations" 
with option of Export.

Through this Export option, you will have query result exported.

Comment: but it says rows are not selected...this has more than 1000 page so how do I select all

Comment: I have successfully exported around 21,000 rows. how many rows do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use the export option at the buttom of the page in the "Query result operations". Edit: (like @Gaurav said +1).

This will export you everything you selected with your query. (No need to click on any checkboxes)

Screenshot to clear things up: [image: phpmyadmin-result-view]

Comment: but it ask for check row and I had more than 1000 pages...how do I check all??

Comment: there is no need to check anything, just use the button labeled export in the grey area